# Playing Video in iOS phonegap Application

Tags: ios

I am sure this is easy but I am having trouble doing it. How do you add a video to an iOS phonegap application. A working example would be awesome.

Comment: Help us help you. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

```
<video id='player' controls src="your url here" 
style="position: absolute; width: 320px; height: 200px;"></video>
```

Using the  tag, very simple for embedding videos.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you just use a normal HTML5 video tag.. For Android you will have to use the video plugin.